# quickly starting up a rails app on a new server; "No command 'puma' found"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

I am trying to quickly set up a rails server. I have an app that I have working an running on my personal computer. Running rails server launches it in localhost:3000 with no issues.

I am trying to start a server on a server to an external IP. So, I followed the instructions here: http://luugiathuy.com/2014/11/setup-nginx-puma-on-ubuntu/ with no issue until I ran: `puma -e production -d -b unix:///tmp/app_name.sock --pidfile /tmp/puma.pid` and got:

```
No command 'puma' found, did you mean:
 Command 'pump' from package 'pump' (universe)
 Command 'pumpa' from package 'pumpa' (universe)
 Command 'duma' from package 'duma' (universe)
```

I have run: `gem install puma` and `bundle install` I have added `gem 'puma'` to my gemfile.

If I visit the external IP of the server I get the nginx error of:

```
 We're sorry, but something went wrong.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

which makes sense since puma isn't running.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
`/bin/bash --login`
```

I believe this worked because before I was not "logged in" to the user that had puma installed